# Why is my webcam messed up in Chrome but fine in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, webcam

I use Ubuntu a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.10 with a Logitech C905 webcam "QuickCam Pro for Notebooks" (2MP, autofocus, etc.). `lsusb` seems to detect the webcam properly as `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0991 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro for Notebooks` and when I test my camera with the Ubuntu built-in **Cheese** app then the image is exactly as it should be.

But when I try using Google Duo or Google Hangouts, then **the image is cut and shifted.** My counterpart receives the same shifted image, so obviously it's pretty useless.

*edit: As per comments, I have discovered that [it works just fine in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8878x.png) so it appears to be a problem with the Google Chrome browser!*

This is Google Duo: [image]

This is Google Hangouts: [image]

Oddly, the test image looks fine for the first half second or so, and then it shifts. Even stranger, the top 10 pixels or so are not shifted. Next time I tried, the top pixels were shifted as well, and my counterpart told me that I was far off-center when I was directly in front of the camera. My elbow was in center.

I've also tested the webcam in a browser using https://webcamtests.com and the [first image it shows it shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj7TQ.png), then that disappears, [then a good image appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN8ri.png) and stays good.

I can't find any Linux drivers on the Logitech website, and given that the image is fine using Cheese, I am also very hesitant to spend money on a new webcam (this one was expensive).

What steps can I take to pinpoint the cause and fix the problem?

Comment: @user68186 I just did, and it's OK just as Cheese is OK.

Comment: How about changing the browser? Firefox vs Chrome? Try another video calling app like Skype, or Zoom. It may be browser or Google's (Hangout, Duo) issue. Let's try something non-Google. It is unlikely to be the driver.

Comment: Zoinks! You are correct! I just tried Google Hangouts and Google Duo **using Firefox and that worked just fine!!** So it's a problem with Google Chrome -- I wonder how I can get **that** fixed. I edited the question to reflect this new finding.

Comment: Since this looks like a Chrome bug and bugs are off-topic here. I suggest you report it to Google. Here is what I found when I Goggled how to report bugs for Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for that link, you made it easy for me. I've submitted it including a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with Chrome. I've also got an old Logitech cam and it only fails in Firefox (all sites) but works elsewhere (mostly using Skype). Others on the web have this very issue of a video split in halves with other specific apps. For me, it only happens ~90% of the time in Firefox, 0% in other apps. I guess it's a Logitech thing. That was a constant across all reports I've found. Everything else (system, OS, apps) was varying. Webcams are getting old. – Update: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1251 Camera-specific issue.